# Adding value to only one slot

Tags: arrays, ruby, immutability

I'm trying to add values to a single slot in an Array. E.g.:

```
a = Array.new(3,[])    # => [[],[],[]]
a[1] << "value"        # => [[],["value"],[]]
```

However, value gets added to all slots in the array.

```
# => [["value"],["value"],["value"]]
```

Is there a reason for this behavior? Is there a standard way to add values to an array to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You're running into a "common gotcha", which is explained in the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas

Comment: "common gotcha's" I hoped that it was a list of common mistakes, but it's only the one. Anyhow, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this behaviour because the new arrays refer to the same object. You can verify that looking at the `object_id`s of the sub-arrays:

```
a = Array.new(3, [])
p a[1] << "value"
p a[0].object_id
# => 70175034559160
p a[1].object_id
# => 70175034559160
p a[2].object_id
# => 70175034559160
```

You can do it this way:

```
a = []
(1..3).each { |e| a << [] }
a[1] << "value"
p a
# => [[], ["value"], []]
```

Or, even better to use this:

```
a = Array.new(3) { Array.new }
```

As shown in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) provided by `@orde` in the comment section.

Comment: And how will I attribute a different value to each slot of the array?

Comment: Please look at my updated code.

Comment: This answer is way better than the "duplicate" one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051442/2d-array-pushing-to-one-array-shows-up-in-all-arrays

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought the "like" from the OP was always the ones marked in green. But now I know the subtle difference.

Comment: Great to hear that it cleared up your confusion and now you understand the difference between those two :) Happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your array like this to ensure each element gets its own array:

```
a = Array.new(3){ Array.new } # or a = Array.new(3){ [] }
```

And, yes, as stated in the other answer, you're seeing this because the same array object is being assigned to each element when you're initializing it. What you're doing is essentially the same as:

```
a1 = Array.new
a2 = Array.new(3, a1)
```

There's nothing wrong with the way you're adding values.

Comment: thanks man! it's 100% clear now.